# Craft 3: Cron job to run Controller actionIndex method of a Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, plugins, cron

I have made a Craft 3 plugin that is manually used in the Craft Admin CP area; click a button and we sync products in Craft with a Shopify API. Now I am trying to automate the process.

[image: Craft 3 Admin CP Plugin Section]

I would like to schedule a task that runs the controller that is executed when an admin user manually clicks the *Manual Sync* button, shown above. Clicking the button runs the actionIndex() method of my plugin's controller, which extends the Craft 3 web controller:

```
<?php

namespace vendor\shopify\controllers;

use \vendor\shopify\Shopify;
use craft\elements\Entry;
use craft\elements\MatrixBlock;
use DateTime;

class SyncController extends \craft\web\Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $apiKey = \vendor\shopify\Shopify::getInstance()->getSettings()->apiKey;
        $password = \vendor\shopify\Shopify::getInstance()->getSettings()->password;
        $secret = \vendor\shopify\Shopify::getInstance()->getSettings()->secret;
        $hostname = \vendor\shopify\Shopify::getInstance()->getSettings()->hostname;

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://$apiKey:$password@$hostname/admin/products.json",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "cache-control: no-cache"
            ),
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
            \Craft::info("(Vendor Shopify plugin) cURL Error #:" . $err, __METHOD__);
        }
        else {
            $section = \Craft::$app->sections->getSectionByHandle('products');
            $entryTypes = $section->getEntryTypes();

            foreach (json_decode($response)->products as $product) {
                $query = Entry::find();
                $query->section('products');
                $query->shopifyProduct($product->id);
                $currentEntries = $query->exists();

                if ($currentEntries) {
                    $existingEntry = $query->all();
                    $existingEntry = $existingEntry[0];
                    $blockIds = [];

                    $field = \Craft::$app->getFields()->getFieldByHandle('productVariants');
                    $existingMatrixQuery = $existingEntry->getFieldValue('productVariants');

                    foreach ($existingMatrixQuery->all() as $block) {
                        $blockIds[] = $block->id;
                        \Craft::info("(Vendor Shopify plugin) Block Id??: " . json_encode($block->id), __METHOD__);
                    }

                    $serializedMatrix = $field->serializeValue($existingMatrixQuery, $existingEntry);

                    if (count($product->variants) === count($blockIds)) {
                        foreach ($product->variants as $key => $variant) {
                            $serializedMatrix[$blockIds[$key]] = [
                                'type' => 'productVariant',
                                'enabled' => true,
                                'fields' => [
                                    'sku' => $variant->sku,
                                    'variantSize' => $variant->title,
                                    'variantPrice' => number_format((float)$variant->price, 2, '.', ''),
                                    'variantCompareAtPrice' => number_format((float)$variant->compare_at_price, 2, '.', ''),
                                    'variantQuantity' => $variant->inventory_quantity,
                                ]
                            ];
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $serializedMatrix = [];
                        foreach ($product->variants as $key => $variant) {
                            $serializedMatrix['new' . $key] = [
                                'type' => 'productVariant',
                                'enabled' => true,
                                'fields' => [
                                    'sku' => $variant->sku,
                                    'variantSize' => $variant->title,
                                    'variantPrice' => number_format((float)$variant->price, 2, '.', ''),
                                    'variantCompareAtPrice' => number_format((float)$variant->compare_at_price, 2, '.', ''),
                                    'variantQuantity' => $variant->inventory_quantity,
                                ]
                            ];
                        }
                    };

                    $existingEntry->setFieldValues([
                        'productDescription' => $product->body_html,
                        'productVariants' => $serializedMatrix,
                    ]);

                    $success = \Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($existingEntry);

                    if (!$success) {
                        \Craft::info("(Vendor Shopify plugin) Error Saving Product: " . $product->title . " " . $err, __METHOD__);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        \Craft::$app->getSession()->setNotice('Manual Sync complete.');
        return $this->renderTemplate('shopify/done');
    }
}
```

So far, I have explored options discussed in these two StackExchange questions that are somewhat related to my issue ([Call Craft controller with cron job](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16233/call-craft-controller-with-cron-job) and [Craft TaskService Overview/Cron Job](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12973/craft-taskservice-overview-cron-job)). Unfortunately my labors haven't been fruitful! I am open to any and all suggestions in regards to how I might accomplish the automation of calling this plugin class's actionIndex method. Thank you, I sincerely appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add console command in your plugin then use third party cron job package to run the console command, your console command will be responsible for calling index function. i had similar kind of requirement earlier, i accomplished this using third party cron job package which was dependency for my plugin to work.

There is new craft 3 plugin call scheduler https://github.com/supercool/scheduler.

I am not 100% sure that this idea will work on your side but just a heads up for you to get started.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion about console commands - this is what I ended up doing today and it worked perfectly. I will post another answer about this to follow up. I appreciate you taking the time to steer me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

I took the route of adding a controller with methods that could be triggered as craft console commands, and then simply ran these commands via cron tasks.

In the **init()** public method of the main plugin class, I added the console commands controller:

```
public function init()
{
   // ...

   // Add in our console commands
   if (Craft::$app instanceof ConsoleApplication) {
      $this->controllerNamespace = 'vendor\shopify\console\controllers';
   }

   // ...
}
```

Inside this namespace of console controllers above, I have a single controller named **CronCroller**, which extends *yii\console\Controller*:

```
<?php

namespace vendor\shopify\console\controllers;

use vendor\shopify\Shopify;

use Craft;
use yii\console\Controller;
use craft\elements\Entry;

/**
 * Shopify plugin commands for cron automation
 *
 * The first line of this class docblock is displayed as the description
 * of the Console Command in ./craft help
 *
 * Craft can be invoked via commandline console by using the `./craft` command
 * from the project root.
 *
 * Console Commands are just controllers that are invoked to handle console
 * actions. The segment routing is plugin-name/controller-name/action-name
 *
 * The actionIndex() method is what is executed if no sub-commands are supplied.
 *
 * Actions must be in 'kebab-case' so actionDoSomething() maps to 'do-something'
 *
 */
class CronController extends Controller
{
    // Public Methods
    // =========================================================================

    /**
     * Run Shopify product Sync
     *
     * The first line of this method docblock is displayed as the description
     * of the Console Command in ./craft help
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionSync()
    {
        echo "\nSyncing Craft products with Shopify.\n";

        // [Automated Task Processes]

        echo "\nSuccess.\n";
        return;
    }
}
```

Since the name of the controller is *CronController*, I can run the code in the **actionSync()** public method through the terminal with a command like:

```
php craft shopify/cron/sync;
```

[PluginFactory.io](https://pluginfactory.io/) is a terrific resource for exploring and learning more, which is how I set up my plugin's console commands.